Fedora 40: ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
I have an issue with running the `Insightfull.io` Workpuls app on my Fedora 40.
I've installed it as an executable file so all I did :
./Workpuls.AppImage
The application launched successfully but I got this error in my terminal:
╰─❯ ./Workpuls.AppImage                                                                                                                                                                    [264438:0525/153707.047497:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`
The app window showed up, but when I pressed Check out button on the App to start the timer:
Desktop file not found for a specified executable.
Xlib: extension "MIT-SCREEN-SAVER" missing on display ":0".
Xlib: extension "MIT-SCREEN-SAVER" missing on display ":0".
./Workpuls.AppImage --no-sandbox but it doesn't seem to work, I get the same errors.
After the app is launched it will auto close in a few minutes after a punch on errors on the terminal
I searched a lot but I got nothing xD, it's been like one week with the problem
expecting to run the app successfully with no issues, please :)
